# Use trained weight to train different dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I have trained a CNN model on a dataset that contains 4 output classes, I saved the model's weights in "weights.h5". I want to use these weights to train on a different dataset that contains only 2 output classes, how can I do so?

Comment: How does your code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load model/weights
2. Remove last layer from trained network
3. Attach new output layer
4. Recompile

```
base_model.load_weights(...)

x = base_model.layers[-2].output
x = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x) # 2 output classes
model = Model(base_model.input,x)

model.compile(...)
```